# Javascript - Use array to iterate through fields?

Tags: javascript

I have a form and would like to verify that a few fields that it contains have an entry.

As such I have the following:

```
        var requiredFields = array(
                                'Delivery_first_name',
                                'Delivery_last_name',
                                'Delivery_address',
                                'Delivery_city',
                                'Delivery_zip',
                                'Delivery_phone'
        );
        for(var field in requiredFields)
        {
            if(document.ezpay.field.value.length == 0)
            {
                document.ezpay.field.style.cssText = 'background:red;';
            }
        }
```

However it does not appear to be working. My thoughts are that the `field` portion of  `if(document.ezpay.field.value.length == 0)`" is not being evaluated.

In other words, the statement is executing as  `if(document.ezpay.field.value.length == 0)` rather than  `if(document.ezpay.Delivery_first_name.value.length == 0).`

Can anyone confirm that belief and more importantly give me some guidance as to why the above is not working?

The goal of the above is to iterate through the defined fields and set the CSS style background to red for any fields that are empty.

Thanks!  :)

Comment: You should really probably use an off the shelf forms validation plugin

Comment: I really think you should try to apprehend javascript *before* programming in it. The array declaration is wrong. The loop is wrong. The way you apply style is wrong. Please find yourself a nice js manual and work it through.

Comment: Try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't iterate over an array using `for...in` as that construct is for enumerating object properties.

Secondly, you are trying to access a property named `field` when what you want is to access a property whose name is contained in a variable named `field`. Try:

```
for (var i = 0, j = requiredFields.length; i < j; i++)
{
    if (document.ezpay[requiredFields[i]].value.length == 0)
    {
        document.ezpay[requiredFields[i]].style.cssText = 'background:red;';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your input fields to have the same name & id attributes and use:

```
if(document.getElementById(field).value.length == 0)
{
    document.getElementById(field).style.cssText = 'background:red;';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
document.ezpay[field].value.length
```

I'm not sure js will evaluate your `field` string when using the dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

NickFitz had the right idea

Here is how I would do it in plain JS

```
var requiredFields = ['Delivery_first_name',
                      'Delivery_last_name',
                      'Delivery_address',
                      'Delivery_city',
                      'Delivery_zip',
                      'Delivery_phone'];

function validate(theForm) {    
  for(var i=0,n=requiredFields.length;i<n;i++) {
    var field = theForm[requiredFields[i]]; 
    if (field.value.length == 0) {
      field.style.backgroundColor ="red";
      return false;
    }
    else field.style.backgroundColor ="white";
  }
  return true; // allow submit
}
window.onload=function(){
  document.forms[0].onsubmit=function() { return validate(this);}
}
```

If you want all empty fields to turn red do this

```
function validate(theForm) { 
  var isOk = true;   
  for(var i=0,n=requiredFields.length;i<n;i++) {
    var field = theForm[requiredFields[i]]; 
    if (field.value.length == 0) {
      field.style.backgroundColor ="red";
      isOk=false;
    }
    else field.style.backgroundColor ="white";
  }
  return isOk; // allow or disallow submit
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional code and display of what else could be done.

Answer (score -1):

Uhmm... try to assign attribute "id" for the fields

```
<input type="text" name="FIELDNAME" id="FIELDNAME" />
```

then you can use

```
for(var field in requiredFields){
    var elem = document.getElementById(field);
    if(elem.value == '') {
       //your proccess
    }
}
```

or maybe you can try using jquery and jquery validate... are more easy and customizable..

Comment: What is it with people thinking nothing can be done without JQuery? It really isn't worth loading an entire library for the sake of what is essentially four lines of code.

Comment: depends of the task... some task are better works with simple javascript... and other is more easy using a framework like jquery...